# Remove minutes and seconds and then convert to UTC timezone

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have column with time stamp data like this

> 2021-12-09 08:01:00.520

I want to remove the minutes and second and then convert the date to UTC timezone in one line.

I tried this code

```
 SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, Time_Stamp), 0) From Table1
```

I get this result

> 2021-12-09 08:00:00.000

and I tried this code

```
SELECT DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), Time_Stamp)From Table1
```

I get this result

> 2021-12-09 16:01:00.520

What I expected is

> 2021-12-09 16:00:00.000

How to combine the select statement into one line in simple way

Comment: How do you know what the time zone of the original is? You can't necessarily rely on working backwards because you might (not) be in DST now, or there are times which overlap when DST changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way.

To remove the minute, seconds and only keep the hour, you may use the following query

```
DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, Time_Stamp), 0)
```

To convert to the `UTCDate`, just find the different in hour () between `GETDATE()` and `GETUTCDATE()` (Since you are not interested in the minute and seconds anyway) and add that to the above query

Putting all together

```
DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, Time_Stamp) + DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date to a string and truncate to remove the minutes and seconds. Then add the difference in minutes between your timezone and UTC.

```
select dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,getdate(),getutcdate()),convert(datetime2(0),convert(varchar(13),getdate(),126)+':00:00',126));
```

Comment: I tried select dateadd(hour,datediff(minute,getdate(),getutcdate()),convert(datetime2,convert(varchar(13),getdate(),126)+':00:00',126)); but I get 2021-12-09 16:00:00.0000000. Not quite as per expected. How to remove trailing zeros?

Comment: Change `datetime2` to `datetime2(0)`.

Comment: Ok I tried that and it works. But I just realize the date did not change to UTC time 2021-12-09 08:00:00 supposed  2021-12-09 16:00:00

Comment: Works for me, please provide a [mre] with the datetime and timezone of the value you are trying to convert, and the results of `getdate()` and `getutcdate()`.

Comment: IMO the whole premise of the question is wrong, because the current time zone might not be the one which was when the date was created. If you know the exact offset then you can use `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` to convert, anything else is just meaningless

Comment: AT TIME ZONE is for SQL 2016 above. this is older version. I specifically put SQL 2014 in title but was edited by other person

Comment: @Jimmy I moves the SQL-Server-2014 to a **tag** which is where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Time_Stamp), 0)) FROM Table1
```